# How can I convert a query string into a a shorter alphanumeric string (and convert it back again) in PHP?

Tags: php, function, hash

I want to store the query string of the current URL as a shorter alphanumeric string with the ability to convert it back to the original query string.

For example:
`inputType=timeline&count=50&hashtag=%23li&filterspecifiedhashtag=1&filterhashtagsend=1&filterscreennames=1&extracturl=1&deshortifyurl=1&filterurls=1`

I want to be able to use the resultant alphanumeric string as a filename.

I want to avoid using MYSQL or storing values in a text file.

Is there a way to convert to an alphanumeric string as well as being able to convert it back to the original query string? I am not very knowledgeable about hashing but wondering whether some kind of "two way hashing" technique could work?

Comment: you can just create a map using session

Comment: @DevZer0 - I won't be able to do this I don't think because it will be running in the background on a cron job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeking is not a hash - since hash is a one-way function in common case.
Here is a possible solution - use both base64 encryption and something like parameters map, so you will able to get shorter file name because you'll not store parameters names, only values:

```
class Holder
{
   const NAME_PARAM_DELIMIER = '|';

   public static function getParametersMap()
   {
      return [
        0 => 'count',
        1 => 'deshortifyurl',
        2 => 'extracturl',
        3 => 'filterhashtagsend',
        4 => 'filterscreennames',
        5 => 'filterspecifiedhashtag',
        6 => 'filterurls',
        7 => 'hashtag',
        8 => 'inputType',
      ];
   }

   public static function getParamsByName($sName, $bReturnAsArray=true)
   {
      $rgParams = @array_combine(self::getParametersMap(), explode(self::NAME_PARAM_DELIMIER, base64_decode($sName)));
      if(!is_array($rgParams))
      {
         return null;
      }
      return $bReturnAsArray?$rgParams:http_build_query($rgParams);
   }

   public static function getNameByParams($sQuery)
   {
      parse_str($sQuery, $rgParams);
      ksort($rgParams);
      return base64_encode(join(self::NAME_PARAM_DELIMIER, array_values($rgParams)));
   }
}
$sQuery = 'inputType=timeline&count=50&hashtag=%23li&filterspecifiedhashtag=1&filterhashtagsend=1&filterscreennames=1&extracturl=1&deshortifyurl=1&filterurls=1';

$sName  = Holder::getNameByParams($sQuery);
$rgData = Holder::getParamsByName($sName);
var_dump($sName); //NTB8MXwxfDF8MXwxfDF8I2xpfHRpbWVsaW5l
var_dump($rgData);
```

Also note that base64 will produce "=" symbols - I am not sure that it is allowed on all file systems (I'm using Reiser, so it's ok in my case)

Comment: Thanks for this. I think I understand the thought behind your method, although I don't understand the code itself. I'm getting a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['` error for line 3. Could you explain what's supposed to happen here?

Comment: Ah, yes. I'm using PHP 5.5; short array syntax via [..] is available since 5.4 version - it seems you need to update your PHP

Comment: Thanks for the update, I was wondering what kind of magic you were using! ;-)
Unfortunately I'm not able to upgrade my PHP to 5.5 for a number of reasons but more importantly the app I am writing needs to work in all version of v5 otherwise I'll have many unhappy people! Looks like I will have to look up short array syntax as I've not come across this yet.

Comment: Just replace `[..]` to `array(..)`

Comment: Thanks, I think this is a really good approach. In the end I decided to store the strings in a text file (despite initially wanting to avoid this method) as it enables me to do a few other things in my project. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use base64_encode() and base64_decode(), but if you want it as a filename, you'll likely hit filename length limit of filesystem (255 chars for ext3). If it's possible you hit this limit, you can use each X chars as directory name, and create full path.